# Performance impact of ng-csp directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, content-security-policy

Enabling content-security-policy and adding the [ng-csp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) directive prevents Angular from using `Function()` and `eval()` for certain optimization.

The doc states that performance can decrease up to 30%.

I was wondering what angular features are actually really impacted by using the ng-csp directive.

Are there workarounds, patterns or other ideas that can reduce the cost of using that directive?

Comment: you can probably reduce lookups by caching paths, or making shallow aliases to deep paths (eg. `a.x=a.b.c.d.e.x`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research and the easiest way to understand the performance hit is by looking at the [initial commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2b87c814ab70eaaff6359ce1a118f348c8bd2197?diff=unified) ([see issue on Github too](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/893)) that introduced CSP support in AngularJs back in 2012.

The thing is that you need to use resolutions of (sub)expressions like

```
a.b.c.d.e
```

e.g.

```
user.data.books
```

in Angular expressions in your HTML template files. Angular parser for this used originally [new Function(arguments, code)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to parse these expressions. However, to support CSP you can't use `new Function()` or `eval()`. The magic number 30% seems to come from http://jsperf.com/angularjs-parse-getter/4 ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2b87c814ab70eaaff6359ce1a118f348c8bd2197?diff=unified#diff-780de070ede30180f6aedb6c5f7d57caR690)). My interpretation of the results is that code with a `for` loop (i.e. jumps in assembly) is slower than code with an inlined/expanded `for` loop.

In the light of the previous paragraphs, I don't believe there is something meaningful you can do to mitigate the performance hit. Maybe (if you are desperate) just don't use long expressions (like `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h`) and use rather short ones but I don't think it's a feasible way to optimize your code.

Fast forward to 2015, AngularJs codebase changed substantially but you can see there are [two parsers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js?source=c#L1674): `ASTInterpreter` (for CSP enabled) and `ASTCompiler` (for CSP disabled). Maybe you can put some performance evaluating code in those parsers to compare `ASTInterpreter` against `ASTCompiler`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Martin. This is really useful